# PHP - How to set regex boundary and not match non alphanumeric char?

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following:

```
$text = 'c c++ c# and other text'; 
$skills = array('c','c++','c#','java',...);

foreach ($skill as $skill) {
    if (preg_match('/\b'.$skill.'\b/', $text)) {
        echo $skill.' is matched';
    }
}
```

In the case of 'c', it matches 'c', 'c#', and 'c++'. I've tried appending assertion (?=\s) or [\s|.] in place of \b towards the end but it needs something similar to \b.

I've checked out other posts but doesn't seem to have the exact situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` matches between `c` and `+` or `#`. You need something like this:

```
$text = 'c c++ c# and other text'; 
$skills = array('c','c++','c#','java');

foreach ($skills as $skill) {
    if (preg_match('/(?<=^|\s)'.preg_quote($skill).'(?:\s|$)/', $text)) {
        echo $skill.' is matched';
    }
}
```

This matches when the text is preceded by either the start of the string (`^`) or a space at the beginning, and followed by either the end of the string (`$`) or a space at the end.

You need to use `preg_quote()`, like I did above, because `c++` contains regex special characters.

Also, note the typo (missing `s`) in `foreach ($skills ... )` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that c++ has regex chars in it. You should use preg_quote on $skill. Then use your back and forward reference solution.

The other issue is that you need to double escape the special characters because php also uses \ as an escape character in strings.